# unable to push my web app into GitHub repository through command line

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push my web app to my GitHub repository, and I wanted to Initialize the Git repository at the root level but I'm getting this error

```
C:\Windows>git init
C:/Windows/.git: Permission denied
```

also when trying the command: git commit -m "first commit"

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'user@DESKTOP-SBN1VHI.(none)')
```

I confirmed that my GitHub repository link is correct . do you know what specifically the problem is?

Comment: there is literally written what you have to do

Comment: i set the user name and email, but I'm getting the same error again:"C:/Windows/.git: Permission denied"

Comment: @Berto99
 C:\Windows>git config --local -l
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.worktree=C:/
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/mawadda0500/codie.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

C:\Windows>git init
C:/Windows/.git: Permission denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git config command will set the authorization to your remote repository, which you already have configured. To resolve the:-  C:/Windows/.git: Permission denied".
Run as administrator or give write permission to .git directory to the logged-in user.

Comment: this was the problem , everything is working fine now , thank you soo muuuch :))))

Answer (score 1):

The "Permission denied" message has nothing to do with access to the remote repository, it refers to the `.git` directory on you local disk. Ensure the user you are running `git` as has write access to this directory.